# Unable to install postgresql on oracle linux with yum

Tags: linux, postgresql-9.1, yum

When i try to install the package it says package is already installed, But when i try to install then it says that no package is available.

```
Downloads $ sudo rpm -i pgdg-oraclelinux91-9.1-7.noarch.rpm
package pgdg-oraclelinux91-9.1-7.noarch is already installed

Downloads $ sudo yum -y install postgresql91 postgresql91-contrib postgresql91-devel postgresql91-libs postgresql91-plperl postgresql91-plpython postgresql91-pltcl postgresql91-docs postgresql91-server
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
Repository google-chrome is listed more than once in the configuration
No package postgresql91 available.
No package postgresql91-contrib available.
No package postgresql91-devel available.
No package postgresql91-libs available.
No package postgresql91-plperl available.
No package postgresql91-plpython available.
No package postgresql91-pltcl available.
No package postgresql91-docs available.
No package postgresql91-server available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yum list postgresql91\*` to find this package first and then use full name to install a package

Comment: The result for the above command is
**Error: No matching Packages to list**

Answer (score -1):

I have facing same issue when downloading postgres in linux.
As i have followed some step from surfing some site. 
I have download **repository RPM** first and its downloaded successfully. 
then after in next step i have run below command

**yum install postgresql10-server postgresql10**

then getting below error

**No package postgresql10-server available.
No package postgresql10 available.**

in resolution of that i have run **yum list** command. and you can find out list of available software where postgres also mentioned so used specific name of postgres in command like

**sudo yum install postgresql-server.x86_64**

And it is working fine.